# Ocelot configuration always returns not found

Tags: .net-core, ocelot

I want to implement an API Gateway using Ocelot. I have successfully tried it on localhost with local APIs, but when I deploy it to our test server, it cannot find the upstream path. It's deployed on IIS with alias. Ocelot is on /gateway and the downstream api on /privacy_api.

My configuration is as follows:

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://test.mydomain.com:8080"
  },
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/privacy_api/api/test/{all}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "http://test.mydomain.com",
          "Port": 8080
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gateway/privacy/api/test/{all}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

No matter what combinations I try on the configuration file, I always get the following error:

[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://test.mydomain.com:8080/gateway/privacy/api/test/dashboard

[WRN] requestId: 0HME3P5BNBTHR:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware setting pipeline errors. IDownstreamRouteFinder returned Error Code: UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError Message: **Failed to match Route configuration for upstream path: /privacy/api/test/dashboard, verb: GET.**

[WRN] requestId: 0HME3P5BNBTHR:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code: UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError Message: Failed to match Route configuration for upstream path: /privacy/api/test/dashboard, verb: GET. errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path:/privacy/api/test/dashboard, request method: GET

Are there any ideas on how to solve this or what am I missing in order to make it work?

Comment: any fix? i have same problem